# How do you set canBecomeFocused for a custom view

Tags: objective-c, uiview, apple-tv, tvos

I am making an application for tvOS. I have a view that contains a `UIButton` and a custom `UIView` that contains a couple other custom views. The simulator is only able to highlight the `UIButton` and not the custom view.

According to the [Building Apple TV Apps Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppleTV_PG/WorkingwiththeAppleTVRemote.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015241-CH5-SW2):

> If your custom view needs to be focusable, override canBecomeFocused to return YES (by default, it returns NO).

According to the [canBecomeFocused Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/canBecomeFocused):

canBecomeFocused will return

> YES if the view can become focused; NO otherwise.

However, attempting to assign YES to canBecomeFocused by doing this:

```
self.customView.canBecomeFocused = YES;
```

Gives this error:

```
No setter method 'setCanBecomeFocused:' for assignment to property
```

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like `UIView` declares the function/property.

Have you tried *overriding* the function like so?

### Swift

```
override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

### Objective-C

```
- (BOOL)canBecomeFocused {
    return YES;
}
```

I haven't tried this, but it may work for you.

Comment: How would this be done in Objective-C (question was specifically for Objective-C)?

Comment: Updated with Objective-C sample - hope this helps

Comment: Should it be `canBecomeFirstResponder` or `canBecomeFocused`?

Comment: canBecomeFocused is used for both Swift and Objective-C. There are no UIFocus API differences between Swift and Objective-C, besides the syntactic differences.

Answer (score 4):

Besides of overriding the `canBecomeFocused` method in your custom view:

```
override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
    return true
}
```

Make sure your custom view `userInteractionEnabled` is true. This is the complete list to be sure your view can be focused:

> Why Is This View Not Focusable?
>
> There are a number of reasons a view that is expected to be focusable may not be, including (but not limited to):
>
> - The view’s canBecomeFocused method returns NO.
> - The view’s hidden
>     property has a value of YES.
> - The view’s alpha property has a value of 0.
> - The view’s user interaction is disabled.
> - The view is obscured by another view on top of it.

Comment: That's exactly how the apple developer website says :)

Answer (score 0):

Above answers are not enough this my customView code block.

**Swift**

```
import UIKit

class Focus: UIView {

    /*
    // Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

    override func canBecomeFocused() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        if context.previouslyFocusedView === self {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                context.previouslyFocusedView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.0, 1.0)
            })
        }

        if context.nextFocusedView === self {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                context.nextFocusedView?.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.4, 1.4)
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Question has the Objective-C tag, not the Swift tag.

Comment: anyone can convert easily from objective-c and swift.

Comment: It still doesn't answer the question since it's in Swift, might as well write in Racket.

Comment: Also just a quick note if you want the animation to be in sync with all other animations on focus use the coordinator as follows : [coordinator addCoordinatedAnimations:^ {
 } completion:nil]; So you just add your changes in the block and they will animate.