# How can I get a specific button running on tvOS (AppleTV) to take focus? (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, focus, tvos

The project have some views with different buttons. When I hide a view and show the other view, I can't get the focus on my button.

I think is related to `setNeedsFocusUpdate`. I have read the Apple doc. There is not any example.

Does anyone know how to do it and put an example (Objective C)?

Comment: Checkout [How do you set canBecomeFocused for a custom view](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32753109/2108547).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to override `preferredFocusedView`, and when you are hiding one view and showing there call this method `setNeedsFocusUpdate`, your `preferredFocusedView` implementation should be something like this

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView
{
    // Add your logic here, it could be more complicated then what is below
    if (view1.hidden)
    {
        return _button;
    }
    else 
    {
        return _button2
    }
}
```

And if you want to make custom view get focus, override `canBecomeFocused` method and return true

**Edit**

You can use add a breakpoint and execute this command `po [buttonYouWantToFocus _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable]` it will tell you why its not focusable.

Comment: First, thank you for your quick response. I have a view with two subviews (menuView and gameView). When I hide menuView and I show gameView, the buttons inside gameView are not focused. As you say, I need to call the method `setNeedsFocusUpdate `. I have try to call it but, I get nothing. Could you show me an example, please?

Comment: Make sure your views are focusable, not hidden and user interaction is enable

Comment: @Moloixo add breakpoint and execute this command on console po [buttonYouWantToFocus _whyIsThisViewNotFocusable] and tell me what it say

Comment: don't override setNeedDisplay, just call it when you are hiding and showing view

Comment: you need to call [self setNeedFocusUpdate], and add breakpoint inside preferredFocusedView and see if you are getting control there,

Comment: SOLVED! setNeedsDisplay is OK, but setNeedDisplay don´t. setNeedsDisplay call - (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {} and then works your code. THANK YOU. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a sub view programmatically, maybe this is what you want:

```
- (UIView *)preferredFocusedView {
    return [view1 preferredFocusedView];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Per!

Answer (score 0):

I realize your question is specific to Objective-C but here is a way to solve for this in Swift.  You need to override the preferredFocusedView property.

```
override var preferredFocusedView: UIView? {
    guard primaryView.hidden == false else {
        return secondaryView
    }
    return primaryView
}
```

Then just call setNeedsFocusUpdate() whenever an event happens that causes your views to be hidden.  Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

Another option (if you don't want to use `preferredFocusedView`) is, instead of setting your view to be hidden, simply remove it from it's superview, like so:

```
myView.removeFromSuperview()
```

This automatically takes the focus away from the button that is removed and gives it to another one that is still on screen.